# Applying Wick's theorem to mass-terms in a free field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, wick-theorem

I'm studying a free field theory in $d$ dimension which consists of two sets of $O(N)$-scalars
\begin{equation}
S = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx \left( \frac{(\partial_\mu\phi^i)^2}{2} + \frac{(\partial_\mu\chi^i)^2}{2} \right) + S_m \ , \quad S_m = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx \left( \frac{m_\phi^2(\phi^i)^2}{2} + \frac{m_\chi^2(\chi^i)^2}{2} \right) \ ,
\end{equation}
where $i \in \{1, ..., N\}$ and the two masses, $m_\phi$ and $m_\chi$, are allowed to differ. I wish to compute
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!} \prod_{a = 1}^{n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx_a \times \\
&\quad \times \langle \left( m_\phi^2(\phi^i)^2 + m_\chi(\chi^i)^2 \right) (x_1) ... \left( m_\phi^2(\phi^i)^2 + m_\chi(\chi^i)^2 \right) (x_n) \rangle \ .
\end{align}
Here I Taylor expanded $S_m$. I'm having problems applying Wick's theorem to the correlator, and are wondering whether somehow can help me with this. I expect the final answer to be resummed into an exponential of
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dy\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle \ , \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dy\langle\chi(x)\chi(y)\rangle \ , \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dy\langle\phi(x)\chi(y)\rangle \ .
\end{equation}
I am not fully sure if this hypothesis is correct though, and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Because the theory is free, the two fields $\phi$ and $\chi$ decouple, as well as their different components. We can $\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle$ into $2N$ different factors, all of which involve only one scalar field. Let us restrict to this case :
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{a = 1}^{n}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx_a  \langle \left( -\frac12 m_\phi^2\phi^2(x_1) \right)... \left( -\frac12 m_\phi^2\phi^2   (x_n) \right)\rangle \\
\end{align}
Let us compute the connected expectation value, to which only the cyclic graph contribute. There are $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ such graphs on $n$ vertices since each vertex, with its two half edges, can sit in two ways inside of it, we get an extra factor of $2^n$. In total, there are  $2^{n-1}(n-1)!$ terms appearing in Wick's theorem. Therefore :
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle_c &= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{2n} \left(- m_\phi^2 \right)^n\prod_{a = 1}^{n}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx_a  \langle \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\rangle  \ldots \langle \phi(x_{n-1})\phi(x_n)\rangle \langle \phi(x_n)\phi(x_1)\rangle\\
\end{align}

We can write this more compactly, if we write $\Delta$ for the operator whose integral kernel is $\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle$ :
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle_c &= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{2n} \left(- m_\phi^2 \right)^n\operatorname{Tr}(\Delta^n)\\
&= \frac12 \operatorname{Tr}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left(-m_\phi^2 \Delta\right)^n\right] \\
&=- \frac12\operatorname{Tr}\log\left(1-m_\phi^2 \Delta\right)
\end{align}
The full correlation function is the exponential of the connected one :
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle &= \exp\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle_c\\
&=\exp\left(- \frac12\operatorname{Tr}\log\left(1- m_\phi^2 \Delta\right)\right)
\end{align}

The full answer with the 2 $O(N)$-scalar fields $\phi^i$ and $\chi^i$ is :
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle &= \exp\Biggl(\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{2n} \left(- m_\phi^2 \right)^n\prod_{a = 1}^{n}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx_a  \langle \phi_{i_1}(x_1)\phi^{i_2}(x_2)\rangle  \ldots \\
&\qquad \qquad \ldots \langle \phi_{i_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\phi^{i_n}(x_n)\rangle \langle \phi_{i_n}(x_n)\phi^{i_1}(x_1)\rangle\\
&\qquad + \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{2n} \left(- m_\chi^2 \right)^n\prod_{a = 1}^{n}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx_a  \langle \chi_{i_1}(x_1)\chi^{i_2}(x_2)\rangle  \ldots \\
&\qquad \qquad \ldots \langle \chi_{i_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\chi^{i_n}(x_n)\rangle \langle \chi_{i_n}(x_n)\chi^{i_1}(x_1)\rangle\Biggl)
\end{align}

**Alternative derivation** (more formal, presented without the details) : we know that the partition function of a quadraction action $S = \frac12 \phi\cdot A\cdot \phi$ is $Z = \int d\phi e^{-S} = N\det(A)^{-1/2}$ where $N$ is a normalization constant, independent of the quadratic form $A$. In our case, the expectation value we are looking for is the ratio of the partition functions of the massive and massless free scalar field :
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle &= \frac{Z[m_\phi]}{Z[0]} \\
&=\left( \frac{\det(-\partial_\mu\partial^\mu)}{\det(-\partial_\mu\partial^\mu+m^2)}\right)^{1/2} 
\end{align}
Since the inverse of $-\partial_\mu\partial^\mu$ is $\Delta$, we get :
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-S_m}\rangle &= \big(\det(1-m^2 \Delta)\big)^{-1/2}\\
&= \exp\left(-\frac12\operatorname{Tr}[\log(1-m^2 \Delta)]\right) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation!

Comment: Are there part of your question that are left unanswered ? If not, would you consider upvoting and accepting the answer ?